# Have object declaration and its exposed methods in separate files - new npm module

Tags: node.js, npm, sails.js

I'm creating a new npm module and I have the object declaration in one file `exchange.js`:

```
var Exchange = function (api_key, api_secret, client_id) {
    this.api_key = api_key;
    this.api_secret = api_secret;
    this.client_id = client_id;

    _.bindAll(this);
};
```

and some other methods like:

```
Exchange.prototype._get = function () {...}
Exchange.prototype._post = function () {...}
```

and ofc, I export the object at the end `module.exports = Exchange;`

Then in the file which contains the methods that will be exposed for external usage (`index.js`), I have:

```
var Exchange = require('./exchange.js');

Exchange.prototype.getOrderBook = function (err, callback) {
    if (err) {
        callback(new Error({'module_error': 'GetOrderBook could not happen.'}));
    }

    this._get('order_book', callback);
};

module.exports = Exchange;
```

And in a 3rd file (`test.js`), used for testing, I try to initialize the object and call the exposed method:

```
var Exchange = require('./index.js');

var exchange_api = new Exchange(
    'XXXXXXXapikeyXXXXXX',
    'XXXXXapisecretXXXX',
    'XXXclientidXXXX'
);

var response = exchange_api.getOrderBook(function (err, data) {
    console.log("response");
    console.log(data);
});
```

but when I run the test script I get an error that `callback is not a function` at the line with `{'module_error': 'GetOrderBook could not happen.'}`. If I simply `return` the error, then nothing happens, but a console log shows that the error if-statment is entered again.

I suspect that the object hasn't been initalized properly in `index.js` since I always enter the `err` check. My aim is to have the declaration of the object + the shared methods (`_get` and `_post`) in one file, and the exposed methods in another one, instead of pushing all the module code in one single `index.js` file.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Exchange.prototype.getOrderBook = function (err, callback) {
```

should be

```
Exchange.prototype.getOrderBook = function (callback) {
```

If you invoke the callback, you should invoke it from _get as

```
callback(new Error({'module_error': 'GetOrderBook could not happen.'});
//or
callback(null, data);
```

There is no reason to make a function which you call with an error parameter(Unless that function is a callback). That would assume you know the error before you even call that function. I think you messed up your logic here a bit.

To clarify even further. you wrote your getOrderBook invocation like this:

```
var response = exchange_api.getOrderBook(function (err, data) {});
```

but with your implementation you should call it as this:

```
var response = exchange_api.getOrderBook(new Error('error'), function (err, data) {});
```

and that just doesn't make sense

If you want a method specific error message you could write it like this:

```
//notice, you don't send in the error, you catch the error
Exchange.prototype.getOrderBook = function (callback) {

    this._get('order_book', function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            callback(new Error({'module_error': 'GetOrderBook could not happen.'})
            return;
        }

        callback(null, data);
    });
};
```

Comment: Is separating the object from the exposed methods in separate files a bad approach? I've read that usually the whole module code is stuffed in the `index.js` file, but that seemed kinda ugly to me. Any suggestion about the logic?